# PHPMyAdmin 403 error in database table search tab

Tags: phpmyadmin, http-status-code-403

We are trying to do a text search in a database table in PHPMyAdmin, but get the error message as shown:
[image: Error in processing request/Error code: 403/Error text: OK]

Text: Error in processing request/Error code: 403/Error text: OK

I assume it's a permissions issue and something is trying to write to disk but I can't find any reference to it anywhere apart from people with the same problem. This is using Chromium on Linux but it has been reported by other people with different desktops.

Comment: What phpMyAdmin version? Any hints in the webserver error log?

Comment: Current version 4.5.4. There's nothing I can see in the logs.

Comment: Does this happen when you first enter the Search page or after trying to press "Go"? Does it happen on every table's search page or only a particular one? Does it happen if you try the demo server at http://demo.phpmyadmin.net ?

Comment: The user has just told me that whitelisting their IP in Cloudflare has made the error go away, which would possibly point at CSS or javascript protection as I presume a front end request would be seen as coming from a Cloudflare address, would that make sense?